# How to define a custom Clean command?

Tags: cmake, clion

I'm calling an existing Makefile for building, so in order to rebuild I'd need to call `make clean` first. I see that `Run | Clean` calls

`cmake --build <dir> --target clean -- -j 4`

Is there a way to make `Run | Clean` run a custom target instead? For instance, one that is defined as:

`add_custom_target(make-clean ALL COMMAND make -C ${mytest_SOURCE_DIR} clean)`

Answer (score 0):

`Run | Clean` action is depends on Project Mode. If you opened CMake project it will always running `cmake --build <dir> --target clean -- -j 4`, but you can create your own External tool and put it in `Run` menu.

1. Create a tool in *Preferences | Tools | External Tools*

[image]

2. Add Tool to Menu *Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars* 
   [image]
3. Profit

[image]